# Write to csv: columns are shifted when item in row is empty (Python)

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

Basic read, al is ok:

```
with open('kres.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        kres.append(row)
```

here i am writing to csv, but columns are shifted when field (item) in row is empty, that's (i assume) because program doesn't know how many columns in file and writes it one by one.
But i want it not to skip empty field, i want it to write some default character or None. I don't know how to check field is empty.

```
with open('kres2.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:    # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(kres)
```

Python 3.3.2 on Windows 7

EDIT:
trying to chak every field in list, but not working

```
with open('article_all_krestianin_ru.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in reader:
        for i in row:
            if i == '':
                i = '-'
            print(row)
        krestianin.append(row)
```

EDIT 2:
['А теперь - про язык;Окт 21', ' 2008;Окт 21', ' 2008А теперь - про язык спрашивала', ' как ;http://www.krestianin.ru/articles/5541.php']

this is from console, all 4 items in place (delimiter ;). Any of that items can be missing, one or even 2, so if 2 of 4 are missing i want to put "-" on their places

Comment: I think you need to change the actual CSV file, not the code

Comment: @ton1c it's an option, of course, do you think there is now way to do that in code?

Comment: If you know how much element should be in the row, and where which on should be, then you can just add additional element to your `kres` list. Or you can read CSV file and where needed just add "the empty element" as `-` (something, something, **-,** something)

Comment: You don't have empty element in you CSV file. If you would have it, then your code would skip the empty columns. So this code that you updated is useless. Try to post the actual full row that you are reading from the file.

Comment: The only element you can check is last one (the link), just by using regex. I speak Russian, and this information doesn't have any  
sense or sequence. You can't check it.

Comment: P.S. I can see that the CSV file contains the name of article, the date, the random word in the article(or the one that goes after the name of the cook), and the link to this article. Would it be much more sense to re-scrap the data from the article and make an useful (user friendly) CSV file? It easily can be done, with small script...

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't understand how CSV module works in Python. Let's say that `kres.csv` file has this data in it:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

Then when you execute this code:

```
import csv

kres = []

with open('kres.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        kres.append(row)
```

The output will be:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

So you are gettin the lists, each list is a row that you read.

If you have this data in your kres.csv file:

```
1,2,3,5,6,7
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

and you need the output to be something like this:

```
['1', '2', '3', '-', '5', '6', '7']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Then you need to write a check, which first will check how many elements are in the row (in this case if it's less than 7 then you are misssing some element(s). After that you need to find which element is missing. For that you need to know that `4` (as in this example), should be exactly after `3` and before `5`.

You can write this checks using Regex (of course it depends on the data that you have in your CSV file) and you will have to check each element (is the elemtn in the right column, list possition).

You can do that programmatically, but not using CSV module.

---

The empty element in CSV file is presented like this:

```
1,2,3,,5,6,7
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

So the output of the code will be:

```
['1', '2', '3', '', '5', '6', '7']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

`,,` and `'',` is the empty element

Comment: ok, you described all right, i can use len(list) to check number of items. But how to check what is missing? Data in items differs a lot, so no way to use regexp

Comment: `print len(row)` will give you the length of the list. If you can't check the row, then there is no way of doing this. Only manually. Register which rows have missing element in them and manually edit them by comparing input and output CSV file

Comment: Sounds all right, you may need to go through the rows with missing items yourself and determine what's missing on some criteria (which will depend on the sort of patterns you'd expect in the CSV data).

Comment: hmm, very strange: now i inspected console output and output file: some items are not missing, but columns are shifted!
by the way: some items in my row list are not quoted ' ' as in your anwer example - and these items are missing

Comment: Because you don't have them in CSV file... that's what I was trying to explain to you... Anyway, as I said, try to re-scrap the data to the CVS file, and when you are scrapping it just make a check: if nothing was scrapped add an `-` instead of value. This will allow you to keep the structure of the columns when reading/writing the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

Before export to CSV you should fill all missing field with None values:

```
def normalizing_dict_list(list):
    """
    Fill all empty and missed dict keys. I.e.
    [{'bar':1, 'foo':2}, {'foo':10, 'baz':20}] converts to
    [{'bar':1, 'foo':2, 'baz':None},{'bar':None, 'foo':10, 'baz':20}]

    """
    # init key list
    keys_list=[]
    for asset in list:
        for key in asset.keys():
            # add new keys to list
            if not key in keys_list:
                keys_list.append(key)

    # init result list
    normal_dict=[]
    for asset in list:
        normal_asset={}

        # iterate every possible keys
        for key in keys_list:
            normal_asset[key]=asset.get(key)
        normal_dict.append(normal_asset)
    return normal_dict
```

and the export list

```
norm_list = normalizing_dict_list(list_with_missed_fields)

with open('export.csv', 'w',newline='') as out_csv:
        writer = csv.writer(out_csv)
        writer.writerow(norm_list[0].keys())
        for obj in norm_list:
            writer.writerow(obj.values())
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to change code - all works well.
First, i was wrong in detecting the type of my obstacle: i thought it were missing fields but that was a Excel 2010 default open settings.
Short answer: csv *correctly* deals with ;; in file, columns are not shifted.

But columns were shifted with default opening in Excel: some ; were not correctly identified by Excel 2010, so data were merged in first column.
Looks like: `'Some text;18.08.2009;`  - first  ; is not detected.

How to import correctly:

Go to Data tab
2. Choose import from file
3. In import wizard choose   data with delimiters
4. Next, Choose ; as delimeter
5. Here is the answer: by default strings are divided by " but need to change it to '